# Are there any unlockables in Assassin's Creed Revelations from playing the prior games?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations, assassins-creed-series

Are there any unlockables in *Assassin's Creed Revelations* that are awarded from playing prior *Assassin's Creed* games or getting specific achievements in those games?

Comment: I haven't got it yet, so I can't answer, but I doubt it. AC2 and AC:B didn't have anything like that IIRC.

Comment: UPS delivered my copy to the leasing office at my complex and I didn't get home before they closed for the day >.< I should be able to confirm 100% tomorrow, but I agree with @MrSmooth that the answer is probably "No".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If you've played AC:B multiplayer that unlocks the [Courtesan](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Courtesan_%28Animi_Avatar%29) for use in Revelations multiplayer.

That's it though.

Answer (score 4):

Now that I've finally had a chance to sit down and play this - no.  I have full completion on all the other games, and started this one essentially naked.